# Are calloc/malloc faster than operator new in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

What I want to know is that if I use calloc/malloc in a c++ program instead of operator  new, does it make the memory allocation faster or it hardly matters as c++ compiler is being used to compile the program.

Edit:

I suppose it should have been taken as obvious that I am not using new operator to call the constructor. Just memory allocation like for an array.

Comment: Questions asking if `x` is faster than `y` should mostly be answered with `benchmark it!`

Comment: In most contexts in C++, `malloc` is inappropriate.  So it doesn't really matter whether it's fast or not.

Comment: You need to spell it `operator new` to avoid all the reactions about apples and oranges.

Comment: Maybe you should post examples of the type of calls to `malloc`, `calloc` and `operator new` or the `new` operator you are trying to compare.

Comment: It would have been obvious if you had stated it. At it is, it would have been unwarranted guesswork to assume any such thing. Unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: @HamZa while benchmarking it yourself can be good and faster than asking (it saves everybody some time), in the long run it will save everybody that has the same doubt some time because they don't have to benchmark it, and hopefully grant some insight of why it's faster, slower or the same.

Comment: @HamZa What the last guy said. Why the hell would you spend all that time benchmarking it yourself when someone obviously did it in the past 40 years C++ has existed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With most compilers I've tested, the extra initialization carried out when you use `new` means that it's *minutely* slower than `malloc` (at least when dealing with simple types for which the two are at least vaguely comparable). For example:

```
Test Name:   D000001                         Class Name:  Allocation
CPU Time:        56.8  nanoseconds           plus or minus       2.84
Wall/CPU:        1.02  ratio.                Iteration Count:  419430400
Test Description:
 Dynamic array allocation, use and deallocation time measurement
 Dynamic array of 1000 integers
 get space on heap using malloc() and use it in a procedure on each call



Test Name:   D000002                         Class Name:  Allocation
CPU Time:         238  nanoseconds           plus or minus       11.9
Wall/CPU:        1.03  ratio.                Iteration Count:  104857600
Test Description:
 Dynamic array allocation, initialization, use and deallocation time measurement

 Dynamic array of 1000 integers
 get space on heap using malloc() and use it in a procedure on each call



Test Name:   D000003                         Class Name:  Allocation
CPU Time:        60.4  nanoseconds           plus or minus       3.02
Wall/CPU:        1.02  ratio.                Iteration Count:  419430400
Test Description:
 Dynamic array allocation, use and deallocation time measurement
 Dynamic array of 1000 integers
 get space on heap using NEW and use it in a procedure on each call



Test Name:   D000004                         Class Name:  Allocation
CPU Time:         249  nanoseconds           plus or minus       12.4
Wall/CPU:        1.03  ratio.                Iteration Count:  104857600
Test Description:
 Dynamic array allocation, initialization, use and deallocation time measurement

 Dynamic array of 1000 integers
 get space on heap using NEW and use it in a procedure on each call
```

So, `malloc` is faster on average, but there's enough variation in speed (in both `new` and `malloc`) that an individual invocation of `new` might actually be faster than an individual invocation of `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks for doing those tests

Comment: Hey Jerry, nice answer. One note though, these measurements only hold for the compiler (or compilers) tested.

Comment: @wich: In theory, you're absolutely correct. In fact, however, testing across quite a few compilers suggests that the trend noted above is sufficiently widespread that it it's a fair assumption until or unless you see reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yeah, I would definitely expect most mainstream compilers to be doing roughly the same for `malloc` and `operator new`.

Answer (score 5):

You're comparing apples and oranges. `malloc()` and `calloc()` allocate memory. `new` allocates memory, via a possibly over-ridden operator, *and calls a constructor.* They do different things. Comparing them isn't valid. The fact that 'a C++ compiler is being used to compile the program' is (a) obvious and (b) irrelevant.

Comment: Then consider the case where they are equivalent, i.e. for malloc the case where the constructor does nothing, or for calloc the zero-initialization case. Or compare them to a call to the operator new function. Or better yet close the question as a duplicate...

Comment: @EJP I suppose it is obvious I won't be using new operator to call a constructer in this case.

Comment: @adnankamili It was not obvious at all.

Comment: @MarcGlisse If you're commenting on my answer you're introducing additional constraints that are not stated in the question. If you're commenting on the question you're doing it in the wrong place.

Comment: @EJP I was commenting on your answer, so let me expand: saying that the question is meaningless, because there are cases where it is, doesn't seem as productive as identifying the cases where it has a meaning and concentrating on those. Also, since you have enough rep, you should be closing the question (as a dup), not posting a 3-line answer. PS: I didn't downvote.

Comment: @MarcGlisse If you think it's a duplicate, why don't *you* VTC? I don't accept that it is incumbent on me to find a duplicate. And sometimes a three-line answer is sufficient. Truth isn't a function of length.

Answer (score 4):

`malloc` does the *equivalent* task of `operator new` in c++, not `new operator`. They just allocates a memory location large enough for your need. `new operator` additionally *fills* the allocated memory with *proper* data by creating an `object` by calling the `constructor` in that memory. `calloc` fills in the bit with `zeroes`.

Which one of `malloc/calloc` and `operator new` is *more efficient*? This is implementation dependent. Both allocates memory of certain size of returns as `void*`.

Answer (score 2):

`new` would normally be implemented as a wrapper that just calls `malloc`. The difference is the C++ semantics that it adds (calling constructors, handling exceptions etc).

Answer (score 0):

Like any performance question about C++, it depends on your compiler. But any widely-used compiler will optimize `new` to be as fast as `malloc`. Write a test program and see for yourself.

(I'm assuming you mean something like `new char[100]`, rather than constructing an object)